# How to set autocapitalization on UIAlertView's UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uialertview

Is there any way to set an auto-capitaliztion option on the new `UIAlertView` with text input?
I want this to start with a capital letter:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add Name" message:@"Enter name for routine" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alert show];
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add Name" message:@"Enter name for routine" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three types according to your preferences.

The first is to capitalize the first letter of each word:

```
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

the second is to capitalize all words

```
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
```

the third is to capitalize every word in a sentence

```
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
```